# Do some HTML elements have pseudo-class styling applied to them by default?

Tags: html, css

For example we can look at `<input type="text">`, which by default has slightly darker border on hover and a dark outline on focus (which also varies between browsers). 
The question is: 
Is that default functionality implemented using `:hover` and `:focus` pseudo-classes in browser's default stylesheet? 
If not, what *is* being used here? 
I'm talking strictly about *default* styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most native elements are implemented as html components hidden behind shadow dom. These are indeed styled using basic css just like you would any other. In fact, browsers all have a user agent stylesheet saying how everything is styled by default.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM